# Bubble chart cannot reduce bubbles

Tags: reactjs, highcharts

I just want to reduce the number of bubble maps from the below link. I am able to increase, but cannot reduce it.

.JS libraries are all in sandbox link.

https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-colden-w3kn5

Comment: Hi @Tint.z, That problem looks like a bug, so I reported it here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/11545. The workaround with `immutable` prop looks good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I tried alot of options and i found the answer in documentation.
You can set `immutable={true}` to so it can update the new data feeded to it.

```
<HighchartsReact
      highcharts={Highcharts}
      options={options}
      immutable={true}
    />
```